# sp_send_dbmail - Cannot attach query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

The goal is to embed the following procedure in a SQL Server 2008r2 job that will send a comma delimited text file that can be opened in Excel by non-technical users.  The file should have 1 row per record, include headers, and not be truncated or padded. Overall, a very standard non-special file in my opinion.

However, I'm running into multiple conflicting problems:

- Each individual field onto a separate line.  Each line is padded out to 256 characters with spaces.  This both makes the file virtually unusable and is too big to email. Setting **@query_result_no_padding=1** fixes this problem.
- If each row (including commas) is over 256 characters, that row is truncated and copied to the next row.  Setting **@query_no_truncate=1** *should* fix this but that throws an error when **@query_result_no_padding=1**
- After some trial & error, I don't think @query_no_truncate applies to the headers.  Column headers are pasted over several rows and I'm at a loss on that one.  None of the options in the documentation seem to apply here.

How do I get this to output the query results into a standard text file that can be opened & filtered in Excel?

```
    Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name='myserver',
      @reply_to='repliesgoto@here.com',
      @recipients='me@company.com',

      @subject='my subject line',
      @body=@HTMLbody,
      @body_format='html'

      @query='Select * from myserver.dbo.mytable',
      @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
      @query_attachment_filename='x.txt',
      @query_result_header=1,
      @query_result_separator=',',
      @query_result_no_padding=1,
      --@query_result_width=300,
      --@query_no_truncate=1,
```

My primary documentation for this proc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: looks like the problem is that columns you are selecting from are CHAR.  I bet you get expected results if columns are VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the issue is the CHAR datatypes in the table, as the issue does not happen with VARCHAR.

```
use tempdb
go
create table dbo.t1 (col1 char(10), col2 char(20));
go
insert into dbo.t1 values ('1', '1')
    , ('2', '2')
    , ('3', '3');
go
select quotename(col1), quotename(col2) from dbo.t1;
go
```

Results:

```
[1         ], [1                   ]
[2         ], [2                   ]
[3         ], [3                   ]
```

Now execute the following, but RTRIM the columns:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'test'
, @recipients = 'x@x.com'
, @reply_to = 'x@x.com'
, @subject = 'test2'
, @body_format = 'HTML'
, @query = 'set nocount on; select rtrim(col1) as col1, rtrim(col2) as col2 from dbo.t1'
, @execute_query_database = 'tempdb'
, @attach_query_result_as_file = 1
, @query_attachment_filename='x.txt'
, @query_result_header=1
, @query_result_separator=',';
```

email results of attached file:

```
col1,col2
----,----
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

Comment: I added the rtrims and changed the data type of the fields from NVARCHAR to VARCHAR (they wen't CHAR).  I can't see the data file produced but it's too big to attach to an email (over 20mb).  Can you confirm you tested this with 2008r2 or are you on a newer version?

Comment: The data file should be around 1mb normally.  But all that padding makes it 20+